# How to combine React hooks (useContext, useEffect) with Apollo react hooks (useQuery)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to create a simple component that returns all my organizations from Apollo GraphQL server (query). I want to render all these orgs from a context state where it could be placed with a dispatch method after the component is mounted (handled by *useEffect* hook).

*useEffect* hook should call function **getOrganizations** and then call custom hook *useGetOrganizations* if a state result (organizations array) is empty. *useGetOrganisations* hook uses *useQuery* from @apollo/react-hooks.

Unfortunately, this is not working and my console says that "./src/components/Organisations/Organisations.js
  Line 32:13:  React Hook "useGetOrganisations" is called in function "getOrganisations" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"

Please, can you help me?

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

    import ORGANIZATIONS_QUERY from './OrganizationsGraphql';
    import { Store } from '../../store/Store';

    const Organizations = props => {
        const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(Store);

        useEffect(() => {
            getOrganizations();
        });

        const useGetOrganisations = async () => {
            const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ORGANISATIONS_QUERY);

            if (loading) {
                return 'Loading...';
            }
            if (error) {
                return `Error! ${error.message}`;
            }

            return dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_ORGANISATIONS',
                payload: data.organizations,
            });
        };

        const getOrganizations = () => {
            if (state.organizations.length === 0) {
                useGetOrganizations();
            }
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>All organisations</h1>
                {console.log(state.organizations)}
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default Organizations;
```

Comment: Nevermind... I won't probably work with react context at all. Apollo client local state seems like the solution https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/

Answer (score 0):

Try: (using refetch)

```
    const { data, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(ORGANISATIONS_QUERY);
    const useGetOrganisations = async () => {

        if (loading) {
            return 'Loading...';
        }
        if (error) {
            return `Error! ${error.message}`;
        }

        return dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_ORGANISATIONS',
            payload: data.organizations,
        });
    };
```